# Trying to Add record to mysql using php and html

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm trying to add a record to an sql table, and I'm having trouble doing so.

I have a sign up page that will take in the username, password, and email of the user, and pass them to a small php script which calls functions from a larger php file.

When I try press the signup button, the page just refreshes, and nothing is added to the table.

Any advice is appreciated.

html:

```
  <body>

    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="grad"></div>
        <div class="header">

        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="signup">

    <script     src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/js_functions.js"></script>

    <form method="post" action ="signup_script.php" onsubmit = "return checkEmailandPassword(this);" method = "post" >
                <input   type="text" placeholder="username" name="username"      required = "required" maxlength = "15"><br>
                <input type ="email" placeholder = "email" name = "email" required = "required" maxlength = "50"><br>
                <input type ="email" placeholder = "re-enter email" name = "reemail" required = "required" maxlength = "50"><br>
                <input  type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" required = "required" pattern = "(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{10,}"><br>
                <input  type="password" placeholder="re-enter password"name="repassword" required = "required"><br>
                <p class = "passwordreq">Password must:</p>
                <ol class = "passwordreq"> 
                    <li>Have 10 characters</li>
                    <li>Have one number</li>
                    <li>Have one uppercase letter</li>
                </ol>
                <input type="submit" value="sign up"> <input type="button" value="go back"  onclick="window.location='index.html'">
            </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

small php file:

```
include_once('profile_Functions.php');

    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    createUser($username,$password,$email);
```

large php file:

```
<?php
    extract($_GET);
    extract($_POST);
    extract($_SERVER);

    function setup(){
    extract($_GET);
    extract($_POST);
    extract($_SERVER);

    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $passwd="";

    $connect=mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd) or die("error connecting mysql server");
    mysql_select_db('oddjob',$connect) or die("error accessing db");
}



function createUser($name, $pass, $email){
    setup();
    $hashed_password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "insert into profiles (UserName, Password, Email) values ($name,         $hashed_password, $email); ";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
} ?>
```

Comment: please dont use extract like that, its dangerous

Comment: You have references to `signup_script.php`, `profile_Functions.php`, "small php file", and "large php file".  How are they related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `insert` statement fails. You should surround character values inside the `values` part with quotes:

```
$sql = "insert into profiles (UserName, Password, Email) 
        values ('$name', '$hashed_password', '$email'); ";
```

It would be good to actually check that `$res` is not `false` after the execution of `mysql_query`.

Note that it is unsafe to inject user input values directly into SQL statements. Read about [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks and how you can protect your database from them.

Comment: it would be great to not use mysql_* and unsantised inputs

Comment: Thanks that worked! And I agree that sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @jhell please dont actually use this, your going to get hacked

Comment: @jhell, read about SQL injection and protect your database accordingly.